# Matching comma-separated ranges with a regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a bunch of comma-separated ranges and single numbers like this:

```
100-200,300,400,100-200

300,100-200,100-200,400

300,400,100-200,100-200
```

How do I match these lines individually using a JavaScript regex? I tried `(\w*,\w*(-)\w*,\w*)`, which turned out to match only the second example line partially.

Comment: Please describe nature of these numbers, what should match and what should not.

Comment: Also which approaches you have tried and why their results are not what you want. Generally speaking, for Regex questions, knowing which engine is used might also be helpful.

Comment: What is it your expecting an array of lines and values or an array of all values, also @ma_il it quite clear there using java script regex by the tags and since java script is it's own Regex they have tagged it correctly

Answer (score 1):

Based on your (rather vague) description I think this is what you meant:

```
\d+(?:-\d+)?
```

Should work to get all numbers and ranges. ([Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dep44z/1))

But! if you want it line by line:

```
(?:\d+(?:-\d+)?,?)+
```

As demonstrated [here](https://regex101.com/r/dep44z/2).

Hope it helps!